# Why is Android Studio extremely slow after running my app?

Tags: android-studio

In the last few weeks (maybe since updating to Bumblebee, I'm not sure), Android Studio is extremely slow after running my app on my phone via USB. By that I mean the duration between typing something and getting it displayed is a few seconds. My PC shouldn't be the problem. After restarting Android Studio, everything is fine. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a try uninstalling and installing it again.
I confirm Android Studio has become slow after Bumblebee version when typing, running apps, etc, with Arctic was so much faster. My lap is an i7 11th Gen with 16 GB RAM so it is a problem with the Android Studio.